# C# ASP.net Test if user comes from Local Network

Tags: c#, asp.net, local

I want to use C#/ASP.net to find out whether the user browsing the website is on the same network so that certain links are only displayed while in the office (to those who have access to them).

Anyone accessing from within the office will be doing so by going to it's local IP address (i.e. 192.168.x.x) whereas external users will be browsing to the public domain name.

All I need is some way to differentiate between the two types of user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (Request.UserHostAddress.StartsWith("192.168"))
{
    //localuser
}
```

Comment: Remember host address can be spoofed.

Comment: What is user is using class A or B local address?? Disappointing answer

Answer (score 0):

Take a look @ Request.Url.Host - you'll be able to pluck the address from this.

Comment: Any suggestions on the best way of checking whether a Url is local?

Comment: `Request.Url.Host.StartsWith("192.168")` - lifted from Simon's response below.