# mono(c#) detect if users are on same network

Tags: c#, ios, networking, xamarin.ios

Does anyone know how to detect programmatically in C# whether 2 or more users are on the same network. I have a use case for this in my application. I found this sof question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3250567/c-sharp-asp-net-test-if-user-comes-from-local-network) question which might be a good starting point as mentioned in some of the comments, spoofing might be an issue. So any solution that deters that will be very helpful. Also the question in the link talks about detecting users by ip address while I' looking for users on the same Wifi Network. As always thanks in advance.

EDIT: For a little more Clarity. Say i have UserA, UserB and UserC using my app. UserA and UserB are on WIFI Network name "Foo" while UserC is on Network named "Bar". Of the 3 users using my application, is there a way to detect that the first two users are on the same network. i hope this offers a little more.

Comment: I'm confused, what is doing the detecting?  A server application?  The MonoTouch application?

Comment: @TrevorElliott: I was wondering whether the application can do the detection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a number of options, you could use the MonoTouch.MultipeerConnectivity functionality, or you could send a broadcast a UDP packet and wait for responses.

Comment: @JohnD Cross-platform, UDP is your friend. This might help you to get started: https://github.com/Krumelur/Pyramid/blob/master/Pyramid_CommonMostPlatforms/UDPNetworkService.cs